# Sum of all elements in Rectangular 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am supposed to make a program to add all the elements inside the 2D rectangular array but the answer for this is supposed to be 31, instead it prints 33.
What am I doing wrong?

Heres the code:

```
public static int sum(int[][] array) {
        int[][] numArray = {

                                {3, -1,  4,  0},
                                {5,  9, -2,  6},
                                {5,  3,  7, -8}

                           };
        int sumOfRow = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
            sumOfRow += numArray[0][i];
            sumOfRow += numArray[1][i];
            sumOfRow += numArray[2][i];
        }

        System.out.println(sumOfRow);
        return sumOfRow;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numArray.length` is the number of rows, and your code treats it as the number of columns, so you ignore the last column of each row. The number of columns in a given row is `numArray[i].length`.

You should use nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numArray[i].length; j++) {
        sumOfRow += numArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by the others already,  `numArray.length` refers to the number of rows (or in other words the number of other arrays referenced by the references in `numArray`), and your code treats it as the number of columns and because there are fewer rows than columns you're getting un-expected results.

Nevertheless, the first index for any two-dimensional array should be the row index and the second should indicate the column index. Eran's answer indicates how to solve your current issue.

However, I just wanted to provide another more ideal solution in Java-8+ to sum the elements of your two-dimensional array.

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(numArray)
                .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                .sum();
```

It's more ideal because the `flatMapToInt` is the perfect method for this type of job and simply calling the `sum` terminal operation should render the results you need.

Answer (score 2):

`numArray.length` is the length of outer array, you should use `numArray[0].length` instead of `numArray.length` which should give you expected results.

If you are using java 8, here is the solution:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(numArray)
                .mapToInt(arr->IntStream.of(arr).sum()) // sum the inner array
                .sum(); // sum the outer array
```

Comment: @Pshemo or `.flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)` or better --> `.flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)`.